# 502 Bad Gateway error when reindexing with Solr to localhost address

Tags: solr, indexing

I'm using the Bitnami Solr 6.5.1 installer, and I've used it successfully on other servers. On our QA server, which is sharing CM/CD in one site and has Solr installed locally, I'm getting the following message each time I reindex. This is a custom index that's set up with a rebuild core to swap after a rebuild. Again, I'm using this same setup locally with no problem. The only difference might be that the QA is on an Azure VM, but I set the firewall rules to open a "loopback" to itself just in case that was an issue. So I'm not sure what the issue would be, does anyone have insight?

```
ManagedPoolThread #14 01:55:04 ERROR Exception
Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)

Nested Exception

Exception: SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException
Message: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>502 Proxy Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Proxy Error</h1>
<p>The proxy server received an invalid
response from an upstream server.<br />
The proxy server could not handle the request <em><a href="/solr/content_index_web_temp/update">POST&nbsp;/solr/content_index_web_temp/update</a></em>.<p>
Reason: <strong>Error reading from remote server</strong></p></p>
</body></html>

Source: SolrNet
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.PostStream(String relativeUrl, String contentType, Stream content, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Post(String relativeUrl, String s)
   at SolrNet.Commands.OptimizeCommand.Execute(ISolrConnection connection)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrBasicServer`1.SendAndParseHeader(ISolrCommand cmd)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex.PerformRebuild(Boolean resetIndex, Boolean optimizeOnComplete, IndexingOptions indexingOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex.Rebuild(Boolean resetIndex, Boolean optimizeOnComplete)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Net.WebException
Message: The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway.
Source: System
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at HttpWebAdapters.Adapters.HttpWebRequestAdapter.GetResponse()
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.GetResponse(IHttpWebRequest request)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.PostStream(String relativeUrl, String contentType, Stream content, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
```

Comment: Did you get solution for this issue? Thanks and Regards,
Urvesh

Comment: I stopped using Bitnami and just went with the straight Solr download, then wrote my own Windows service project to manage things (rather than using NSSM or the like).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this into your httpd.conf file

```
Timeout 2400
ProxyTimeout 2400
ProxyBadHeader Ignore
```

This helps to solve the error

Comment: I am unable to find this file. I am facing same issue and want to update or add this file. Could you please tell me where exactly this file is located.